# not able to convert native query result to DTO projection

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Not able to achieve DTO projection using `native query` in `jpa repository`. For single field it is working, but not for multiple fields.

Need to implement this class projection with some complex native query. So I am just exposing the issue I am getting through this two fields scenario.

**JPA repository**

```
public interface CustomerDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerDetail, Integer> {
    @Query(
           value = "SELECT first_name as 'firstName', last_name as 'lastName' FROM customer_details where id=?1 order by customerId desc limit 1", 
           nativeQuery = true)
    CustomCustomerDTO findById2(String id);
}
```

**dto class**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class CustomCustomerDTO implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1334840937329153773L;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    public CustomCustomerDTO(String firstName,String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName=lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

I am getting below exception in response:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.customer.beans.CustomCustomerDTO]
```

However if I remove any one of the fields i.e. either `firstName` or `lastName` from `DTO` and simultaneously from `native query` as well, then I am able to get response giving either first_name or last_name whichever is there.

I want both fields in my response.

*edit:* I also tried with interface projection

```
public interface CustomerObject {
     String getFirstName();
     String getLastName();
}
```

But I am getting very same exception.

Comment: Try to set alias without `' '` something like `SELECT first_name as firstName ...`

Comment: tried. same exception.

Comment: witch version of `spring-data-jpa` are you using ?

Comment: I am using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `1.5.22.RELEASE`

Comment: I tried updating the parent version to `2.2.2.RELEASE`. Now I got exception : `org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.customer.beans.CustomCustomerDTO]`

Answer (score 0):

I was using `jpa` version 1. So, I changed it to 2.

But only this was not enough.

Actually with `native` queries (which are not `JPQL`), DTO class projections does NOT work. Only Interface projection works.

I don't understand how native query having single field manages to map with DTO class projection again having single field. And throws exception if tried with multiple fields. I also included the two field constructor. This is what I have asked in above question.

So as for the solution because DTO class projection did NOT worked with native query, so after changing JPA version from 1 to 2, I also created projection Interface:

```
public interface CustomerObject {
     String getFirstName();
     String getLastName();
}
```

*Notice* the method name convention in this projection interface.. All required field methods appended with `get`.

And in `jpa repository` I collected the `native query` result set to this interface reference.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT first_name as firstName, last_name as lastName FROM customer_details where id=?1 order by customerId desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
CustomerObject findById2(String id);
```

This solved my issue.